# How to delete QML object

Tags: c++, qml

I am trying to delete QML object and recreate object like this：

```
Rectangle{
    property var obj

    signal videoStopped(variant complete)

    function recreate(url){
        if(!obj){
            console.log("createObject")
            obj = videoComponet.createObject(root)
            obj.stopped.connect(function(){
                videoStopped(obj.status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia)
            })
        }
        obj.source = url
        obj.play()
    }
    function stop(){
        obj.destroy() // obj.deleteLater()
    }
    Component{
        id: videoComponet
        Video {
            anchors.fill: parent
            visible: true
            autoPlay: true; autoLoad: true
        }
    }
}
```

C++ side call `recreate` to generate an object and call `stop` to delete it.

1. `recreate` ⇒ console output createObject

   ↓
2. `stop`

   ↓
3. `recreate` ⇒ console no output

Both `obj.destroy()` and `obj.deleteLater()` not worked.
How to forcedly delete the dynamically created object just like delete in C++.

Comment: have you tried setting obj to null after calling destroy? I would also give it an initial value of null    property var obj: null

Comment: Creator has a QML debugger where you could check the value of `obj`, or you could just print it out.

Comment: Add the following please: `Component.onDestruction: console.log('destroy')` to your `Video`-Item in your `Component`, and a `console.log(obj)` as first line of your `function recreate(url)`. Further a `onVideoStopped: console.log(complete)` if you are using this signal somewhere in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

A minor change to [S.M.Mousavi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45078207/691711):
I observed that setting sourceComponent to undefined does not work. I have to set it to null to unload the component. Another option is to set the source to empty string.

```
onClicked: {
    loader.sourceComponent = null; //causes destroying loaded component
}
```

OR

```
onClicked: {
    loader.source = ""; //causes destroying loaded component
}
```

Comment: @mskfisher I don't think it should be an edit; that would conflict with the authors original intent.  However, this answer should go into more detail about the differences it is noting.  I can't tell if it's saying to replace both `onClicked` with the ones listed respectively or what.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Loader` instead.
It loads an Item dynamically and you can destroy it by setting `sourceComponent` property to `undefined`:

```
Loader {
    id: loader
}

Component {
    id: myDynComp
    Rectangle {
        width: 40; height: 40
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}


Row {
    Button {
        width: 120; height: 40
        text: "Load"
        onClicked: {
            loader.sourceComponent = myDynComp; //load/create component dynamically
        }
    }

    Button {
        width: 120; height: 40
        text: "UnLoad"
        onClicked: {
            loader.sourceComponent = undefined; //causes destoying loaded component
        }
    }
}
```